# How to filter or query an object collecting based upon an array in C# Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a C# collection of custom objects, say BookUsers,  which has UserID as one of the property. I have a string array of UserID's in a separate variable. I want to get the subset of the BookUsers collection filtered by the UserID's in the string array. Please let me know how to do this using Linq.

Thanks

Comment: I know how to query by one value, but not by an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bookusers.Where(b=>ids.Contains(b.UserId))
```

You might want to consider placing the array of user ids into a HashSet to reduce the complexity of your inner query.